# how to open test-to-speech setting from flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, settings, text-to-speech

I want to open the the `Text-To-Speech` from flutter app,

I am using the `Android_intent` package,

code:-

```
AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
    action: 'android.settings.SETTINGS',
    componentName: "com.android.settings.TextToSpeechSettings"
);
await intent.launch();
```

I can't seem to find the exact intent to open the TTS setting.

Android setting intents [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Settings)

if there is no specific intent then How to open the TTS setting from the flutter app?

Answer (score 2):

I found the following working code:-

```
AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
    action: 'com.android.settings.TTS_SETTINGS',
);
await intent.launch();
```